# Tsql - Is there an efficient way to query this?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there an efficient or simple way to query this? for example to minimize server load. Thanks!

db table

```
qId     WKDT    WK_ENDT                  SUM_LVL_Sort  ADOCD  ocd  OfficeName     WKLY_AVG  WeekCode
------  ------  -----------------------  ------------  -----  ---  -------------  --------  --------
201112  201110  2011-10-28 00:00:00.000  19.00         NULL   NAT  NATION         2.23      n
201112  201110  2011-10-28 00:00:00.000  13.00         NULL   F09  SAN FRANCISCO  2.20      n
201112  201111  2011-11-25 00:00:00.000  19.00         NULL   NAT  NATION         2.39      n
201112  201111  2011-11-25 00:00:00.000  13.00         NULL   F09  SAN FRANCISCO  2.14      n
201112  201112  2011-12-30 00:00:00.000  19.00         NULL   NAT  NATION         2.37      n
201112  201112  2011-12-30 00:00:00.000  13.00         NULL   F09  SAN FRANCISCO  2.18      n
```

This is the layout I need

```
WK_ENDT                  adocd  ocd  OfficeName     SUM_LVL_Sort  10    11    12
-----------------------  -----  ---  -------------  ------------  ----  ----  ----
2011-10-07 00:00:00.000  NULL   F09  SAN FRANCISCO  13.00         2.2   2.14  2.18
2011-10-07 00:00:00.000  NULL   NAT  NATION         19.00         2.23  2.39  2.37
```

tql query

```
 select TOP 1 (WK_ENDT),
     ,SUM_LVL_Sort
     ,ADOCD     as adocd
     ,Alias   as ocd
     ,OfficeName
     ,(select WKLY_AVG from kpi.dbo.tb_ssi_rzli where SUM_LVL_Sort = 19.00 and RIGHT(wkdt,2) = '10' and weekcode = 'n'  ) as [10]
     ,(select WKLY_AVG from kpi.dbo.tb_ssi_rzli where SUM_LVL_Sort = 19.00 and RIGHT(wkdt,2) = '11' and weekcode = 'n'  ) as [11]
     ,(select WKLY_AVG from kpi.dbo.tb_ssi_rzli where SUM_LVL_Sort = 19.00 and RIGHT(wkdt,2) = '12' and weekcode = 'n'  ) as [12]
from kpi.dbo.tb_ssi_rzli
where SUM_LVL_Sort = 19.00 and right(qId,2) = '12' and WeekCode = 'n'
order by WK_ENDT desc
```

bluefeet's query result

```
WK_ENDT                  SUM_LVL_Sort  adocd  ocd  OfficeName  10    11    12
-----------------------  ------------  -----  ---  ----------  ----  ----  ----
2011-12-30 00:00:00.000  19.00         NULL   NAT  NATION      NULL  NULL  2.37
2011-11-25 00:00:00.000  19.00         NULL   NAT  NATION      NULL  2.39  NULL
2011-10-28 00:00:00.000  19.00         NULL   NAT  NATION      2.23  NULL  NULL
```

Comment: For each `OfficeName`, there are three distinct `WK_ENDT` values in the source but only one (entirely different from the three, incidentally) in the output. What is the rule behind choosing the value for that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
select  (WK_ENDT),
     ,SUM_LVL_Sort
     ,ADOCD   as adocd
     ,Alias   as ocd
     ,OfficeName
     , CASE WHEN RIGHT(wkdt,2) = '10' THEN WKLY_AVG END As [10]
     , CASE WHEN RIGHT(wkdt,2) = '11' THEN WKLY_AVG END As [11]
     , CASE WHEN RIGHT(wkdt,2) = '12' THEN WKLY_AVG END As [12]
from kpi.dbo.tb_ssi_rzli
where SUM_LVL_Sort = 19.00 
    and right(qId,2) = '12'
    --and RIGHT(wkdt,2) IN ('10', '11', '12')
    and WeekCode = 'n'
order by WK_ENDT desc
```

<strike>Edit try this, it looks like you want to get values based on the month:</strike>

<strike>`select TOP 1 (WK_ENDT),
         ,SUM_LVL_Sort
         ,ADOCD   as adocd
         ,Alias   as ocd
         ,OfficeName
         , CASE WHEN month(wkdt) = '10' THEN WKLY_AVG END As [10]
         , CASE WHEN month(wkdt) = '11' THEN WKLY_AVG END As [11]
         , CASE WHEN month(wkdt) = '12' THEN WKLY_AVG END As [12]
    from kpi.dbo.tb_ssi_rzli
    where SUM_LVL_Sort = 19.00 
        and right(qId,2) = '12'
        and WeekCode = 'n'
    order by WK_ENDT desc`</strike>

Comment: @user1672932 please see my edit. If that is not it, then you need to provide same data for `wkdt` because it is not included in the sample you provided. And what is `qId` it is not included either

Comment: @user1672932 see my edit again, you will use the first query. Remove the `TOP 1` to return all records since you had that present you were only getting one record

Comment: the result returns 3 records (above), is there a way to return a single record with all the values, thanks.

Comment: @user1672932 there are 3 records because you have 3 different values for `WK_ENDT` being returned.  If you only want one then you need to decide which one to return